# Ant design multiple select for nested objects

Tags: reactjs, many-to-many, antd, refinejs

I'm building a dashboard using [`refine.dev`](https://refine.dev) and [`AntDesign`](https://ant.design).

One of my entities has Many-to-Many relation that is returned in the API as an array of objects with `id` properties.

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "relations": [
    {
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to build a form with a “multiple select” component. And I follow [this tutorial](https://refine.dev/docs/tutorials/ant-design-tutorial/#editing-a-record). But unfortunately, it has examples only for “many-to-one” relations.

First I generate `selectProps`. This part goes all right.

```js
const { selectProps: relationsSelectProps } = useSelect<Relation>({
  resource: 'relations',
  optionLabel: 'name',
  defaultValue: record?.relations.map((r) => r.id),
});
```

Then starts the problem. When I'm trying to create a form item

```js
<Form.Item
  name={['relations']}
>
  <Select
    mode="multiple"
    {...relationsSelectProps}
  />
</Form.Item>
```

I can't make it work with multiple nested objects.

I tried different name paths: `['relations', 'id']`, and `['relations', '*', 'id']`

Tried to play around with the `normalize` property.

I don't really want to flatten these objects on the backend side, so the question is: what's the best practice to make this work on the react side of the project?

Comment: I don't get exactly what you are trying to achieve. Can you provide an example? Usually a Select-Item with `mode="multiple"` always gives you a `one-to-many` relation.

Comment: Yes. But this one-to-many relation will assign an array of just IDs. But I need it to work with an array of objects `[{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}]` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can do this thing by adding two properties to the `Form.Item` component.

1. `getValueFromEvent` to transform Select's values to form
2. `getValueProps` to do it the other way around

```
<Form.Item
  name={['relations']}
  getValueFromEvent={(values) => {
    return values.map((id: number) => ({ id }));
  }}
  getValueProps={(ids) => {
    return ids?.map(({ id }: { id: number }) => id);
  }}
>
  <Select
    mode="multiple"
    {...selectProps}
  />
</Form.Item>
```

Then the post (patch) request's gonna look the right way:

```
{
  "relations": [
    { "id": 1 },
    { "id": 2 }
  ],
  // other fields
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So the first part regarding how you are trying to set the form item to line up with your model..

The "name" with the {[something, child-of-somthing]} on the Form.Item is basically dot notation

say I have model that has a relation in it e.g

```
  export interface ISubscription {
  id: number;
  sku: string;
  customer: ICustomer
}
```

and the ICustomer looks like this

```
    export interface ICustomer {
      id: number;
      name: string;
      surname:: string;
    }
```

when you set your Form.Item you can get to the nested value using the {[]} like

```
  <Form.Item
     label="Customer"
     name={["customer", "name"]}
     >
      <Input />               
    </Form.Item>
```

Secondly making multiple selects using antd is a lot more invloved when you go outside the basic use case in refine.dev.

I am not 100% sure with your use case but for example when I had to make a multiple select with custom tags in it.

```
<Form.Item label="Custom Tags">
  <Select
    mode="multiple"
    value={customTags}
    onSelect={handleSelect}
    onDeselect={handleDeselect}
  >
    {customTagOptions}
  </Select>
</Form.Item>
```

but you need to make your own custom options similar to this

```
  const customTagOptions = useMemo(() => {
    return tagDataResult?.data
      ?.map(
        // build an array with the id and label for the select option
        (t) => ({ id: t.id, label: `${t.tagType.name} : ${t.name}` })
      )
      .sort(
        // then sort everything
        (a, b) =>
          a.label.localeCompare(b.label, undefined, { sensitivity: "base" })
      )
      .map(
        // then build the final options
        (t) => (
          <Option key={t.id} value={t.id} title={t.label}>
            {t.label}
          </Option>
        )
      );
  }, [tagDataResult?.data]);
```

becuase yeah the antD / refine combo won;t let you do what you want out of the box.. you are fighting against the framework a bit here.

Hope this helps a bit man